# Firebase not working with react typescript properly

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase

I am using react typescript setup using vite.

firebase version : 9.15.0

**This is my firebase.ts**

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth, GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from "@firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "credentials",
  authDomain: "credentials",
  projectId: "credentials",
  storageBucket: "credentials",
  messagingSenderId: "credentials",
  appId: "credentials",
  measurementId: "credentials",
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = getAuth(app);
export const googleProvider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
export const db = getFirestore(app);
```

It shows a blank page.

when i inspected the page, it shows this.

[image]

when i remove `getFirestore(app)` it works fine.

Comment: Let me see this thing: import { auth, googleProvider } from "../utils/firebase";

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `getFirestore(app)` and not `getFirestore()`

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth, GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from "@firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
  ...
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = getAuth(app);
export const googleProvider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
export const db = getFirestore(app);
```

Comment: still does not work.

Comment: FYI - why are you importing getFirestore from `"@firebase/firestore"` and not from `"firebase/firestore"`

Answer (score 0):

Try to exclude firebase in vite's optimizeDeps :

```js
import { sveltekit } from "@sveltejs/kit/vite";
import pkg from "./package.json";

/** @type {import('vite').UserConfig} */
const config = {
  optimizeDeps: {
    exclude: [
      "firebase",
      "firebase/app",
      "firebase/auth",
      "firebase/firestore",
      "firebase/analytics",
    ],
  },
  define: {
    __VERSION: JSON.stringify(pkg.version),
  },
  plugins: [sveltekit()],
};
```

found this solution in [github](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/6926)